# Read stored procedure source code from Sybase ASE 15.7 database

Tags: java, database, sap-ase

I want to get access to the source code of some stored procedures, which are stored in a Sybase ASE 15.7 database.
At the moment I copy the text manually in a textfile and read it via executed java-code from the disk.

Now it is my goal to improve this process: I will get the sourcecode directly from the database within my executed java-code.
Is that possible?
Sorry, I have no idea.

I have Rapid SQL to work on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vince's hint was to use the stored procedure sp_helptext. This stored procedure produces more than one resultset and caused me difficulties.

RobV's answer was to use the stored procedure sp_showtext. This seems the better solution, cause it returns only one resultset. But I tried it with jdbc and it ever throws in a sql exception ("must return a resultset").

After my fails I find another solution, which need against the other two answers only a execution of a select statement. This works for me! Here is the code:

```
    StringBuffer sbSP = new StringBuffer();
    String query = "select c.text "
                  +"from syscomments c, sysobjects o "
                    +"where o.id=c.id and o.name='"+spName+"' order by c.colid";

    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        //loop over every row of the stored procedure
        sbSP.append(rs.getString("text") + "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you could run an ISQL script that calls the stored procedure sp_helptext  to get the code of the stored procedure. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Vince. Thank you very much for your answer. In my sql-tool (rapid sql) it works perfect. But it returns more resultsets than one. After use the methods `getMoreResults()` and `getResultSet` I still don't get access to the resultset which I need. I found another solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Best use sp_showtext; it gives better formatted results (no broken SQL lines) than sp_helptext

Comment: Hello RobV. I tried it to call sp_showtext with jdbc but it everytimes failed cause no resultset was returned (other normal querys works). In my sql-tool (rapid sql) it works perfect. I found another solution for jdbc. Thank you very much for your help